# How can I restrict MUI TimePicker to allow only certain times?

Tags: reactjs, timepicker, material-ui

I am current using MUI [`TimePicker`](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/time-picker) component. I have a use case in which I need to restrict selected time options to at top of the hour(00min) and to at half of hour(30min).Is this possible? I already know I can grab the minutes value after user has selected any minutes and round of to the next hour mark or half hour mark, but I wanted the user To be aware using the UI (time picker) of the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the source code and tests and as far as I can tell that's not supported. The logic to determine the hour/minute based on the click coordinates is hardcoded and there are no options to restrict the range.

As a workaround to restrict the time options you could use a select widget instead, populated with the intervals you care about.

Answer (score 23):

Property `minutesStep`  of material-ui TimePicker component describe how many minutes should be added/subtracted when moving the clock pointer. In your case use value of 30.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer

Comment: Is there a way to hide the other minutes? Or do a grey out to show it like it has been disabled? using css or anything?

Comment: @Kiran you can use timeSteps={{ minutes: 30 }} instead

Answer (score 4):

In **MUI v5**, There is a [`TimePicker`](https://mui.com/components/time-picker) component in the lab package. You can use `minTime`/`maxTime` props to restrict the hours that can be selected. The example below sets the min time to 8 AM and max time to 6:45 PM:

```
<TimePicker
  minTime={new Date(0, 0, 0, 8)}
  maxTime={new Date(0, 0, 0, 18, 45)}
  {...}
/>
```

If you want to restrict the minute unit you can add a `shouldDisableTime` callback, the example below only allows the user to choose from 16 to 59 minutes:

```
<TimePicker
  shouldDisableTime={(timeValue, clockType) => {
    return clockType === "minutes" && timeValue <= 15;
  }}
  {...}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 1):

The solution from NearHuscarl isn't working for me in the latest MUI V5.
A normal javascript Date object isn't working, but with dayjs instead it works.

For DateTime:

```
<DateTimePicker
          minTime={dayjs().set('hour', 8)}
          maxTime={dayjs().set('hour', 17)}
          />
```

And for Time as well:

```
<TimePicker
          minTime={dayjs().set('hour', 8)}
          maxTime={dayjs().set('hour', 17)}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

With latest MUI, a new property `timeSteps` available with a type `{ hours?: number, minutes?: number, seconds?: number }`.

Example:
Following code will only show minute picker with `data 0, 15, 30 and 45`

```
<TimePicker
  timeSteps={{ minutes: 15 }}
  value={value}
  onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
/>
```

**Advantage over `minutesStep`:**

`minutesStep` disables the other minute step. But it will still be displayed in the UI. To get rid of disabled item

[Documentation](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/time-picker/#TimePicker-prop-minutesStep)